# trace inequality of positive definite matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Assume $A,B \in M_n(\Bbb{R})$ are positive definite matrices, show that $$\text{Tr}(AB)\leq \text{Tr}(A)\text{Tr}(B) $$

---

I only prove it for $n=2$, it is straightforward calculate.but when $n \geq 3$. I have no idea to use the condition positive definite. I know it is equal to its principal minors are positive. when $n=2$, is very useful .but when $n \geq 3$. it seems useless : ( please help me ,thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $D$ is a diagonal matrix  with $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ in the diagonal and $b_i>0$ then  $tr(AD)=a_{11}b_1+\ldots a_{nn}b_n$. Since $a_{ii}>0$ and $b_i>0$ then $a_{11}b_1+\ldots +a_{nn}b_n\leq(a_{11}+\ldots +a_{nn})(b_1+\ldots+b_n)=tr(A)tr(D)$.

If $B$ is symmetric then $B=RDR^t$, where $R$ is orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal, and $tr(AB)=tr(ARDR^t)=tr(R^tARD)\leq tr(R^tAR)tr(D)=tr(A)tr(B)$.